# What are Mutators and Accessors in Laravel

Tags: laravel, accessor, mutators

I am trying to understand accessors & mutators and why I need them. And my another ask is the middle part of an attribute's method for an example:

**Accessor**:

```
public function getFirstNameAttribute($value)
{
   return ucfirst($value);
}
```

**Mutator:**

```
public function setFirstNameAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['first_name'] = strtolower($value);
}
```

Here, we can see getFirstNameAttribute and setFirstNameAttribute methods and I haven't been able to clear the middle part **FirstName** of them. I will really be grateful for a better explanation and kind cooperation.

Comment: If you find this kind of question again, spin up empty project and try it yourself before taking time to ask on SO.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Accessors create a "fake" attribute on the object which you can access as if it were a database column.  So if your person has `first_name` and `last_name` attributes, you could write:

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
  return $this->first_name . " " . $this->last_name;
}
```

Then you can call `$user->full_name` and it will return the accessor.  It converts the function name into a snake_case attribute, so `getFooBarBazAttribute` function would be accessible through `$user->foo_bar_baz`.

Mutator is a way to change data when it is set, so if you want all your emails in your database to be lowercase only, you could do:

```
public function setEmailAttribute($value)
{
  $this->attributes['email'] = strtolower($value);
}
```

Then if you did `$user->email = "EMAIL@GMAIL.com"; $user->save();` in the database it would set `email@gmail.com`

Comment: "as if it were a database column"  = spot-on explanation. upvoted!

Comment: I don't think the statement `a "fake" attribute` is completely true. As you can call `$model->name` and the `name` attribute points to a valid table column and you still can have the `getNameAttribute` accessor. Accessors is a place where you want to mutate your data when they are asked for.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)  accessor  and mutator both are public function in Laravel model for getting and setting model's attributes

An **accessor** will automatically be called by Eloquent when attempting to retrieve the value of the first_name attribute:

```
$fullName = $user->full_name;
```

It's for customizing a model's attributes or adding fake attributes

On the other hand **mutator** is for **setting a real attribute** of a model

Mutator will be automatically called when we attempt to set the value of the an attribute

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens that you have to modify the column value that was stored in a database. For Example, if you want to show column values that qualify some condition then you have to use **Accessor and Mutator**. where **Accessor** get value and **Mutator** set value.

By $append=[]; you can create any random column that fulfills your application demand.
here I am only telling about **Accessor**. In this code `total_holiday_hours` is my DB column name and i want to modify that value so that
i used `$this->attributes['total_holiday_hours']` otherwise you can access this way
`$this->total_holiday_hours`.

```
function getTotalHolidayHoursAttribute()
{
    if( $this->attributes['total_holiday_hours'] && $this->holiday_session == date('Y') )
    {
        return $this->attributes['total_holiday_hours'];
    }
    return 225;

}
```